# C#, How to check Hour and minute only from Datetime?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, model-view-controller

I have DateTime column in my database, for example, 2018-08-02 14:00:00. I want to compare date and time( hours and minutes only). So far I have used

> DbFunctions.CreateTime(x.BroadCastOn.Hour, x.BroadCastOn.Minute,0.00)

but it is not giving me the required result

```
var todaysDate= DateTime.Now;   
context.deliverys
          .Where(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DeliveredOn)  == todaysDate.Date  && todaysDate.TimeOfDay == DbFunctions.CreateTime(x.DeliveredOn.Hour, x.DeliveredOn.Minute,0.00).ToList()
```

Comment: You might want `dt.ToString("HH:mm")` or [`ToShortTimeString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshorttimestring.aspx).

Comment: That will only ever be equal for a single second each day... You want to ignore seconds as - so use `todaysDate.Hour` and `todaysDate.Minute`

Comment: Or something like `SqlFunctions.DateName("hh", foo)` ? and compare hh then mm

Comment: Simply todaysDate.TimeOfDay.Hours == x.DeliveredOn.Hour && todaysDate.TimeOfDay.Minutes== x.DeliveredOn.Minute   this worked

Comment: You can directly convert data to consider only hours and minutes only DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy H:mm") and compare.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like your intent is to have seconds as 0, is it? DateTime.Now would hardly ever be have seconds as 0. Probably you meant to ignore seconds instead:

```
var todaysDate= DateTime.Now;   
context.deliverys
   .Where(x => 
       DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DeliveredOn)  == todaysDate.Date  &&
      todaysDate.ToString("HH:mm") ==   
       DbFunctions.CreateTime(x.DeliveredOn.Hour, x.DeliveredOn.Minute,0).ToString(@"hh\:mm")
   .ToList()
```

Comment: This gives me error "No overload for method Tostring takse 1 argument"

Answer (score 0):

Simply,

```
 context.deliverys
          .Where(x => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.DeliveredOn)  == todaysDate.Date  
&& todaysDate.TimeOfDay.Hours == x.DeliveredOn.Hour && todaysDate.TimeOfDay.Minutes== x.DeliveredOn.Minute).ToList()
```